# GGPlot 4 Panels different y

Tags: r

how to produce a plot with 4 different panels everyone has a different value from the data frame.
For example the penguin dataframe from the iris dataset.
I want to have as x axis: the species and as y-axis: 1. culmen_length_mm,   culmen_depth_mm, flipper_length_mm, body_mass_g

Also the maximum and minimum of the plot should also be the max and min of the column.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question will be better received if you give some indication of what you've done so far and where you've gotten stuck; right now it reads as a request to write the code for you, which is not what SO is for ...  In general, the way to do this is to "melt" the data to long format (e.g. using `tidyr::pivot_longer()` and then using `facet_wrap()`

Comment: Using `penguins` and `iris` as public datasets is good, but it's unclear what you are expecting in each plot: scatter? hist? density?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to consider the four columns not as four different variables but as observations of a single factor variable with four levels. Next, you reshape the four columns to two columns, one of which holds the level, the other the value, using `pivot_longer`. After that, you can `facet_wrap` the values, one facet per variable level:

```
library(palmerpenguins)

penguins %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = bill_length_mm:body_mass_g,
                 names_to = 'parameter',
                 values_to = 'value'
                 ) %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_boxplot(aes(x = species, y = value)) +
    facet_wrap( ~ parameter, scales = 'free_y')
```

The rationale behind *tidying* your data is explained in [this chapter](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html) of H. Wickham's R for Data Science.